# GitHub - getting started creating a repo

Tags: git, bash, open-source, github

I followed these instructions from GitHub web page to create a first repo;

```
Global setup:
Set up git
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  git config --global user.email my_mail@gmail.com

Next steps:
  mkdir OpenSourceContrib  
  cd OpenSourceContrib  
  git init
  touch README
  git add README
  git commit -m 'first commit'
  git remote add origin git@github.com:dlib/OpenSourceContrib.git
  git push -u origin master
```

Existing Git Repo?
      cd existing_git_repo
      git remote add origin git@github.com:dlib/OpenSourceContrib.git
      git push -u origin master

Everything goes ok until cd existing_git_repo ; then, I tried several path in the following command 'git remote add origin ...' (notably, I first tried with the path where README file is located, beginning c:/Users/...). Now, when I write this precise bash command

```
  git remote add origin git@github.com:dlib/OpenSourceContrib.git
```

I get

```
  fatal: remote origin already exists
```

and when I write the next command,

```
  git push -u origin master
```

I have the following error

```
  ERROR: repository not found
  fatal: The remote ended up unexpectedly
```

I don't understand where this errors are coming from, how to remove for instance the remote origin to start from scratch again, or how to fix it.

Btw, could you point to good quick reference to bash?

Regards.

Comment: Where does existing_git_repo come from?  Do you really have a pre-existing repo, or is the README commit the only commit?  Are you using [these](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/) instructions?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen yes, these are the instructions ; the README is the only commit. It is located in a so called Hello-World folder in  C:/User/myName path.

Comment: I don't follow.  Is your repo OpenSourceContrib or Hello-World?  If you cd into `C:/User/myName/Hello-World`, then do `git remote -v`, what is the output?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen thanks. I get origin git@github.com:myName/Hello-World.git (fetch) origin git@github.com:myName/Hello-World.git (push) (on two lines)

Comment: And what happens if you do `git push -u origin master` in that same directory?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I write same cd as before, then `git push -u origin master`, and after I entered my (correct) ssh password, I have again `ERROR: repository not found` .

Comment: What is the actual name of the repository on GitHub?  For example, the name of [this one](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as) is jbossas/jboss-as.  If you go your list of repos (or the page for the repo itself), what is the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question, command sequences and subsequent comments are not adding up.  You apparently already have a repository in 'Hello-World' - suggesting you followed the GitHub instructions.  But now, when creating OpenSourceContrib, you appear to be in the 'Hello-World' source tree (with .git repository) - hence the 'origin already exists'.

Just start again.  Create a new GitHub repository and carefully create your source code tree with local Git repository)

Answer (score 0):

You could also edit the text file .git/config and make your `origin` remote to point to the right location (here `git@github.com:dlib/OpenSourceContrib.git`).